# javascript pass multipart/form-data with pdf file

Tags: javascript, form-data, cucumberjs

I am trying to pass a multipart/form-data for cucumber testing of a rest post api. I need to pass a pdf file. I am referring to https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data. Here is my code:

```
let form = new FormData()    
form.append('content', process.stdout, {
        filename: 'test.pdf', // ... or:
        filepath: pdffilepath,
        contentType: 'application/pdf',
        knownLength: fs.statSync(pdffilepath).size
    });
await axios.post(url, form, {
  headers: {
    ...form.getHeaders(),
    'Content-Length': form.getLengthSync(),
    'content-type': multipart/for-data boundary=' + form.getBoundary()
}
});
```

If I pass process.stdout as one parameter in append function, it timed-out. I don't have any stdout object.
I tried different form.append call by using fs.createReadStream, but it sends file octate stream. I want to send file type as pdf.
Any help on this?

Comment: Don't provide your own headers overwriting `form.getHeaders()`

Comment: I have to provide headers for the authentication. Which objects need to be passed as stdout. As I am calling this from cucumber tests, I don't have stdout object. I tried to pass process.stdout, but it is just giving me error as timed out.

Comment: I meant `content-length` and `content-type`, don't overwrite those